# Ajax call causes net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache, .htaccess

I am experiencing `net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING` error in Chrome randomly when Ajax calls are made inside the application. For example:

```
$.get('https://mydomain/myapi/getAll')
Object {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: function,
 getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}
        jquery.js:8625 GET https://mydomain/myapi/getAllnet::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
```

Back-end that is returning JSON data is using PHP(5.3.9) with Apache(2.2.29).

These are response headers:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, must-revalidate
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Thu, 30 Apr 2015 14:25:49 GMT
Expires:Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified:Thu, 30 Apr 2015 14:25:50 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

and the only uncommon thing that I can find in htaccess configuration is

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
```

I don't have access to the back-end, but I'm supposed to guess what's really causing problems here. Same application is running without any problems in the WAMP environment, if it means something. What is most likely to cause this error?

Comment: Seeing similar things with a Ruby-based backend, which uses the `Rack::Chunked` middleware (meaning that I also get a Transfer-Encoding: chunked response back). The strange thing is, when I request the URL in the _browser_ or via curl, all works fine...